# building tk window application for file searching

Tags: file, recursion, tcl, tk-toolkit, proc

hi I am buliding a window tool where there will be one entry for directory pattern and  a return entry for giving out the number of files of a particular pattern and calculate button hitting which i will get the number of files in the return entry.[image]

The code is :

```
          package require Tk

          wm title . "Validating number of files"
          grid [ttk::frame .c -padding "3 3 12 12"] -column 0 -row 0 -sticky nwes
          grid columnconfigure . 0 -weight 1; grid rowconfigure . 0 -weight 1

          #takes the input value for directory_Pattern
          grid [ttk::entry .c.directory_Pattern -width 20 -textvariable directory_Pattern] -column 2 -row 1 -sticky we
          grid [ttk::entry .c.numberOfFiles -width 20 -textvariable numberOfFiles] -column 2 -row 2 -sticky we
          grid [ttk::button .c.glob-r -text "Calculate" -command glob-r] -column 3 -row 3 -sticky w

          grid [ttk::label .c.flbl -text "directory_Pattern"] -column 3 -row 1 -sticky w
          grid [ttk::label .c.islbl -text "is equivalent to"] -column 1 -row 2 -sticky e
          grid [ttk::label .c.mlbl -text "numberOfFiles"] -column 3 -row 2 -sticky w

          foreach w [winfo children .c] {grid configure $w -padx 5 -pady 5}
          focus .c.directory_Pattern

          bind . <Return> {glob-r}

          proc glob-r {{dir .} args} {
          if {[catch {
             set res {}
             foreach i [lsort [glob -nocomplain -dir $dir *]] {
             if {[file isdirectory $i]} {
                    eval [list lappend res] [eval [linsert $args 0 glob-r $i]]
             } else {
                    if {[llength $args]} {
                       foreach arg $args {
                       if {[string match $arg $i]} {
                          lappend res $i
                          break
                       }
                    }
                    } else {
                           lappend res $i
                      }
                   }
           }
         return $res
         set ::numberOfFiles [$res]
         }]!=""} {
         set ::numberOfFiles "no files are there"
         }
         }
```

but when I entered "E: *.tcl" in directory_patter , I am getting "no files are there" in numberOfFiles on clicking calculate button.
Could someone please help?

Comment: any reply for this query

Comment: I might be missing something, but I can't see where you use `directory_Pattern`...

Comment: @captain: thanks to figure it out , I have given it in focus. yet the code is not working

Comment: thanks captain. you decoded it and it was my issue only. thanks once again.it resolved

Comment: There are a lot of problems with this script. One that stands out is that if you call `return` inside a `catch` script, the `catch` command will always return 2 (and the result argument to `return` will be stored in the variable named in the second argument to `catch` (which you don't provide here).

Comment: thanks Hoodiecrow...you are right..I had issue now it get resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `directory_Pattern` to the `glob-r` procedure when you first call it - at the moment it goes nowhere!

```
grid [ttk::button .c.glob-r -text "Calculate" -command {glob-r $directory_Pattern}] -column 3 -row 3 -sticky w
```

Comment: thanks for highlighting it but still after changes i am not getting the desired output